# Console.WriteLine string formatting not outputing expected result

Tags: c#, string-formatting, console.writeline

```
Console.WriteLine( "Year{0,20}", "Amount on deposit" );
```

output: `Year    Amount on deposit`

As I understand it, 16 spaces should follow the word "Year". However, As you can see the, that is not the case. There are only 4 spaces after the word.  Is the code interpreted in a different manner than what I understand it to be?

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly it is.  The formatting is not applied to "Year", it is applied to the argument you pass.

Comment: I'm rusty with C#, but I think the `{0,20}` is doing something like forcing "Amount on deposit" to take up 20 spaces by padding to its left.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually three spaces. Add in a symbol to help you understand what's going on:

```
Console.WriteLine("#Year#{0,20}#", "Amount on deposit");
```

Output:

```
#Year#   Amount on deposit#
```

The string "Amount on deposit" is taking up 20 spaces - 17 for the actual text, and 3 characters of padding before it. It's like right alignment, as [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format) explains.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks all for your inputs. :)

Answer (score 0):

The 20 represents alignment. So your total string size is going to be 20 characters.

So "Amount on deposit" = 17 chars + 3 chars padding = 20

See [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is applied to the substitute.  So the spacing is `20 - <length of string>`.

Answer (score 0):

To get an output with 16 spaces after year you can reverse what you have into

`Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}Amount on deposit", "Year");`

This will create an empty space of 20 chars before "Amount on deposit", which "Year" gets put into.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, without using any format specifiers:

Left Justified:

```
Console.WriteLine( "{0}{1}", year.ToString().PadRight(20,' '), "Amount on deposit" );
```

Right Justified:

```
Console.WriteLine( "{0}{1}", year.ToString().PadLeft(20,' '), "Amount on deposit" );
```

So the left justified version will output the year, followed by 16 spaces:

```
|1994                |
```

The right justified version will output 16 spaces, followed by the year:

```
|                1994|
```

Answer (score 0):

the following will print `Amount on deposit` right aligned in a 20 charactar space

```
Console.WriteLine( "Year{0,20}", "Amount on deposit" );
Result:
"Year   Amount on deposit"
```

if you want it left aligned use the minus sign:

```
Console.WriteLine( "Year{0,-20}", "Amount on deposit" );
Result
"YearAmount on deposit   "
```